# Find lowest positive missing integer in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have array with integers something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 10]
```

My question is what is the easiest way to get lowest positive integer that is not already in this array?

Something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 10].lowest_available => 4
[1, 8, 3, 6, 10].lowest_available => 2
[5, 8, 3, 6, 10].lowest_available => 1
```

Does any one have an idea how to manage this in ruby?

Comment: what do you mean by "lowest available"? In `[1, 2, 3, 6, 10]` lowest value is 1.

Comment: What is "pseido code"?

Comment: By lowest i mean integer that is > 0 and not already in the array. Sorry for not making myself clear.

Comment: would `[1, 2, 3].lowest_available` return `4` or `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By lowest i mean integer that is > 0 and not already in the array

Basically you are looking for the first value that is not equal to its `index+1` when sorted. Here:

```
def lowest_available(arr)
  res = nil
  arr.sort.each.with_index(1) { |a, i|
    if i != a
      res = i
      break
    end
  }
  res
end

lowest_available([1, 2, 3, 6, 10])
# => 4

lowest_available([1, 8, 3, 6, 10])
# => 2

lowest_available([5, 8, 3, 6, 10])
# => 1
```

**Update**

The above method can be shortened by returning value along with `break`. (As suggested by Cary and Stefan in comments below).

```
def lowest_available(arr)
  arr.sort.find.with_index(1) { |a, i| break i if i != a }
end
```

Comment: yes that is pretty much what i went for...i was just thinking if there isn't something like that already made for ruby :)

Comment: That was a nice observation about the relationship between each value and its index. Two suggestions: 1) use `find` and 2) write `each.with_index(1)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland if I use `find` in say `.to_enum.with_index(1).find { |a, i| i != a }` it will return both value and index in an Array. Wont selecting index from returned array be confusing?

Comment: thanks for suggestion #1. I edited my answer accordingly. Definitely improved. :)

Comment: `break` can return a value: `arr.sort.each.with_index(1) { |a, i| break i if i != a }` or you could use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: Minor correction: in order to work for "complete" arrays like `[1,2,3]`, you'd have to use `arr.sort.each.with_index(1) { |a, i| return i if i != a } && nil`

Comment: `&& nil` will always return `nil`. Using `find` instead fixes the problem. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: `find` is even better, nice

Comment: this only works with positive numbers, what about if the array contains negative numbers?

Answer (score 4):

```
class Array
  def lowest_available; (1..Float::INFINITY).find{|e| include?(e).!} end
end

[1, 2, 3, 6, 10].lowest_available # => 4
[1, 8, 3, 6, 10].lowest_available # => 2
[5, 8, 3, 6, 10].lowest_available # => 1
```

or, as suggested by Stefan:

```
class Array
  def lowest_available; 1.step.find{|e| include?(e).!} end
end
```

Comment: `(1..Float::INFINITY).find` can be expressed as `1.step.find`

Comment: Is there any reason to use `include?(e).!` instead of `!include?(e)`?

Comment: @Stefan 1. Thanks for the suggestion. 2.  
Is there any reason to use `!include?(e)` instead of `include?(e).!`?

Comment: Isn't prefix notation common for unary operators?

Comment: I don't care what is common. I care more about consistency. I don't understand why there is a chain of methods, and all of a sudden, negation has to be unary operator.

Comment: You don't write `(1.-@)` instead of `-1`, do you? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan I don't because that method is not designed to be used like that. In fact, you need extra at-mark and parentheses. It is not possible to use that within a method chain (without parentheses, which breaks the method chain).

Comment: I know, I know :-) I was just wondering because I've never seen or used `obj.!` before.

Answer (score 2):

Not that elegant, but if your arrays are small, you could create the entire integer array and use [`Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) to find the difference:

```
def lowest_available(arr)
  ((1..arr.size).to_a - arr).first
end

lowest_available([1, 2, 3, 6, 10]) #=> 4
lowest_available([1, 8, 3, 6, 10]) #=> 2
lowest_available([5, 8, 3, 6, 10]) #=> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the lowest possible number > 0 in an array containing negative values, I would add something to the given solution by [@shivam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367766/14048071), and finally, a function looks something like this:

```rb
def lowest_element(arr)
  res = nil
  arr = arr.reject { |e| e < 0 }
  arr.sort.each.with_index(1) do |e, i|
    if i != e
      res = i
      break
    end
  end
  res.nil? ? (arr.size > 0 ? arr.sort.last + 1 : 1) : res
end

lowest_element([1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 7, 2]) => 4
lowest_element([1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 7, 2, 4]) => 9
lowest_element([-1, -7, -9]) => 1
lowest_element([-1, -7, -9, 1]) => 2
lowest_element([-1, -7, -9, 0]) => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the array
2. Iterate over the array and compare each item's value with the current index+1, if this pair is not equal you found the lowest available integer which is index+1.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (it's late):

```
def first_missing(a)
  a.reduce(0) { |tot,n|
    exp=expected(tot); return exp if n>exp; tot + n }
end

def expected(tot)
  ((-1.0 + Math.sqrt(1.0+8*tot))/2).round + 1
end

first_missing([1, 2, 3, 6, 10]) #=> 4
first_missing([1, 8, 3, 6, 10]) #=> 2
first_missing([5, 8, 3, 6, 10]) #=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way

```
def lowest_available (array)
  min = array.min
  max = array.max
  number = (min..max).to_a - array
  number = array.select { |v| v>0 }
  number = number.min + 1
end
```

What I am doing is to create another array that contains all numbers in the interval of the array in question.
Once that is done, I remove the original array numbers from the created array
Then I add 1 to the lowest number